# How can I get the row and column number when the user clicks in a particular column table in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

If the user clicks a particular column in a html table, how can I get the row and column number of it.

```
  $("table #id").click(function()
  {
          //get row and column num
  });
```

Comment: <table>
 <tr>
 <td id="tbCell" name="c00"></td>
 <td id="tbCell" name="c01"></td>
 <td id="tbCell" name="c02"></td>
 </tr><table>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `#id` is a `td` element:

```
var myRow = $(this).parent('tr').index();
var myCol = $(this).index();
```

Of course, more complex table structures require more complex selectors. You'd need to show your HTML for further assistance.

Comment: Gah. Thanks. Too late at night.

Comment: yes #id is a cell.Could you please tell  me of what is row in  parent('row') and what is its significance.

Comment: Edited. See comments above.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest:

```
$('td').click(function (){
    var cell = this,
          col = cell.cellIndex + 1,
          row = cell.parentNode.rowIndex + 1;
    console.log('Row: '  + row + ', column: ' + col)
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/RxgwH/22/).

Answer (score 0):

This should be pretty straight forward:

HTML

```
<p class="result"></p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>row 1 - cell 1</td>
        <td>row 1 - cell 2</td>
        <td>row 2 - cell 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row 2 - cell 1</td>
        <td>row 2 - cell 2</td>
        <td>row 2 - cell 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row 3 - cell 1</td>
        <td>row 3 - cell 2</td>
        <td>row 3 - cell 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
var $result = $(".result");
$("table").on("click", "td", function(e) {
    var $tableCell = $(this);
    var tableCellNumber = $tableCell.index() + 1;
    var tableRowNumber = $tableCell.parent().index() + 1;

    var result = "row number: " + tableRowNumber + ", cell number: " + tableCellNumber;

    $result.text(result);
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Varinder/Rr7JS/

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$("table tr td").click(function() {
    var rowNo = ($(this).parent().index() + 1);
    var cellNo = ($(this).index() + 1);
    alert("rowNo=" + rowNo + "  ||  cellNo=" + cellNo);
});
```